# AWS CodePipeline deploy Spring Boot application to Elastic BeansTalk no .jar file at root level of your source

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I built a simple CodePipeline for a SpringBoot Java application with 3 steps:

```
Source: get the source from GitHub 
Build: a jar file 
Deploy: to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance
```

I had this error in logs

> An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] -
> [CheckProcfileForJavaApplication]. Stop running the command. Error:
> there is no Procfile and no .jar file at root level of your source
> bundle

My Buildspec:

```
version: 0.2

#env:
  #variables:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #parameter-store:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #secrets-manager:
     # key: secret-id:json-key:version-stage:version-id
     # key: secret-id:json-key:version-stage:version-id
  #exported-variables:
     # - variable
     # - variable
  #git-credential-helper: yes
#batch:
  #fast-fail: true
  #build-list:
  #build-matrix:
  #build-graph:
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
    #If you use the Ubuntu standard image 2.0 or later, you must specify runtime-versions.
    #If you specify runtime-versions and use an image other than Ubuntu standard image 2.0, the build fails.
    #runtime-versions:
      # name: version
      # name: version
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  #pre_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn install
      # - command
      # - command
  #post_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
#reports:
  #report-name-or-arn:
    #files:
      # - location
      # - location
    #base-directory: location
    #discard-paths: yes
    #file-format: JunitXml | CucumberJson
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/sbk-0.0.2.jar
    # - location
    # - location
  #name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  #discard-paths: yes
  #base-directory: location
#cache:
  #paths:
    # - paths
```

[image]

it'is work fine when I upload manualy to EBS but when do it withe the pipeline , its doesnt work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

AWS BS dont found the jar in the pckaging folder, he found target/xx.jar
What i did is i move the jar to main folder
with this commande

```
  - mv target/*.jar app.jar
```

full of buildspec

```
 version: 0.2
    
    phases:
      install:
        runtime-versions:emphasized text
          java: corretto11
        commands:
          - echo install
      pre_build:
        commands:
          - echo pre_build
      build:
        commands:
          - mvn package
          - echo build
      post_build:
        commands:
          - echo post_build
          - mv target/*.jar app.jar
    
    artifacts:
      files:
        - app.jar
```